# Overpass api. How to determine the default speed for highway tag (inside, outside parameters)

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

i use this request to get the higeway tag

[out:json];way(around:10,32.151272,34.894703)["highway"];(._;>;);out body;

then I try to determine the speed value from this table but I don't understand how to get the "inside" "outside" parameters

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_tags_for_routing/Maxspeed#Default_speed_limits_by_country

[image]